# Seeking a book where theory follows application, but theory doesn't suffer

Tags: reference-request

I'm a Ph.D. student in pure math (algebraic topology) going into my fourth year. I'm interested in visiting Earth.

I have a dream book in mind: in my dream book, the discussions begins with particular real-world problems, as concrete as can be, and then discusses how various math techniques can be applied. A chapter might start with a description of an easy-to-understand, complicated-to-solve problem, and then survey various approaches, to whet the reader's palate to learn more about each one.

The title might be *A Survey of Applied Math for Pure Mathematicians*, in the vein of Spivak's *Physics for Mathematicians*. It might also be written somewhat in the spirit of *A User's Guide to Algebraic Topology*, which aims to move quickly, allowing the reader to fill in what details she wishes.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to look at the [Princeton Companion to Applied Mathematics](https://www.amazon.com/Princeton-Companion-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0691150397).  Also, while this is not exactly what you're looking for, Boyd and Vandenberghe's textbook Convex Optimization contains a lot of applications of convex optimization.  I also recommend looking at their new textbook [Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/vmls/), which discusses many applications of least squares to applied problems.